# Binary Tree in C

Tags: c, tree, pointers

It takes integers from argv[] and inserts into tree, making sure to allocate memory and free that memory once the program has finished. How can I improve code quality, what are your suggestions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct treenode {
    int i;
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
};

void insert(struct treenode **t, int v){
    if(*t == NULL){
        struct treenode *x = malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
        x->i = v;
        x->left = NULL;
        x->right = NULL;
        *t = x;
    } else if ( v < (*t)->i ) {
        insert(&(*t)->left, v);
    } else if (v > (*t)-> i) {
        insert(&(*t)->right, v);
    }
}

void printNode(struct treenode **t){
    if(*t == NULL){
    } else {
        printf("%i \n", (*t)->i);
        printNode(&(*t)->left);
        printNode(&(*t)->right);
    }
}

void freeNode(struct treenode **t){

    if ((*t)->left != NULL) {
        freeNode(&(*t)->left);
    }
    if ((*t)->right != NULL) {
        freeNode(&(*t)->right);
    }
    free(*t);

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct treenode *root = NULL;
    insert(&root, 5);

    for(int i=1; i<argc; ++i){
        insert(&root, atoi(argv[i]));
    }
    printNode(&root);
    freeNode(&root);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advice 1**

```
struct treenode *root = NULL;
```

I suggest you roll an explicit `struct` for the tree with a more describing name:

```
typedef struct binary_tree_t {
    ...
} binary_tree_t;
```

**Advice 2**

`printNode()` could be modified to do in-order traversal simply by rearranging the three statements:

```
printNode(&(*t)->left);
printf("%i \n", (*t)->i);
printNode(&(*t)->right);
```

**Advice 3**

I suggest you spit your data structure implementation into a header (`*.h`) and an implementation file (`*.c`).

**Alternative implementation**

I had this in mind:

**binary_tree.h**

```
#ifndef NET_CODERODDE_BINARY_TREE_H
#define NET_CODERODDE_BINARY_TREE_H

typedef struct binary_tree_node_t {
    int datum;
    struct binary_tree_node_t* left;
    struct binary_tree_node_t* right;
} binary_tree_node_t;

typedef struct binary_tree_t {
    binary_tree_node_t* root;
} binary_tree_t;

int binary_tree_t_init(binary_tree_t* tree);
int binary_tree_t_insert(binary_tree_t* tree, int datum);
void binary_tree_t_print(binary_tree_t* tree);
void binary_tree_t_free(binary_tree_t* tree);

#endif /* NET_CODERODDE_BINARY_TREE_H */
```

**binary_tree.c**

```
#include "binary_tree.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int binary_tree_t_init(binary_tree_t* tree)
{
    if (!tree)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    tree->root = NULL;
    return 1;
}

int binary_tree_t_insert(binary_tree_t* tree, int datum)
{
    binary_tree_node_t* new_node;
    binary_tree_node_t* curr_node;
    binary_tree_node_t* prev_node;

    if (!tree)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);

    if (!new_node)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    new_node->left  = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;
    new_node->datum = datum;

    if (!tree->root)
    {
        tree->root = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        prev_node = NULL;
        curr_node = tree->root;

        while (curr_node)
        {
            if (datum < curr_node->datum)
            {
                prev_node = curr_node;
                curr_node = curr_node->left;
            }
            else if (datum > curr_node->datum)
            {
                prev_node = curr_node;
                curr_node = curr_node->right;
            }
            else
            {
                /* datum already in the tree */
                return 1;
            }
        }

        if (datum < prev_node->datum)
        {
            prev_node->left = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            prev_node->right = new_node;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

static void binary_tree_t_print_impl(binary_tree_node_t* node)
{
    if (!node)
    {
        return;
    }

    binary_tree_t_print_impl(node->left);
    printf("%d ", node->datum);
    binary_tree_t_print_impl(node->right);
}

void binary_tree_t_print(binary_tree_t* tree)
{
    if (!tree)
    {
        printf("null tree");
        return;
    }

    binary_tree_t_print_impl(tree->root);
}

static void binary_tree_t_free_impl(binary_tree_node_t* node)
{
    if (!node)
    {
        return;
    }

    binary_tree_t_free_impl(node->left);
    binary_tree_t_free_impl(node->right);
    free(node);
}

void binary_tree_t_free(binary_tree_t* tree)
{
    if (!tree)
    {
        return;
    }

    binary_tree_t_free_impl(tree->root);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- `printNode` and `freeNode` are misnomers. These functions do not print and free the individual node, but the entire tree. `printTree` and `freeTree` look more appropriate.
- An empty `if` clause in `printTree` looks unpleasant. Early return is perfectly OK.
- Passing a double pointer to seems like an overkill. A simple pointer works well and honestly is more readable, e.g.

  ```
      void freeTree(struct treenode * root)
      {
          if (root == NULL) {
              return;
          }
          freeTree(root->left);
          freeTree(root->right);
          free(root);
      }
  ```
- Insertion doesn't need to be recursive. The compiler *may* recognize a tail recursion and optimize it out, but I recommend to be explicit.